# FCM push not wokring in one plus 8

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried the following solution but it stops working my push notification. I just wanted to stop my firebase service from getting killed by doze mode. I tried different solutions like sending priority as high in payload but that also didn't work.

```
 <service android:name=".backgroundmanager.BackgroundOperationsManagerService" android:enabled="true" android:process="com.hashedin.processname" />



 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
             alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 30000, pendingIntent);
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
             alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 30000, pendingIntent);
            } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 30000, pendingIntent);
            }

<receiver android:name=".backgroundmanager.alarmmanager.AlarmBroadCastReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:process="com.hashedin.processname"/>

public class AlarmBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        {
            PowerManager.WakeLock  screenWakeLock;
            Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast fired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                        "myapp:ScreenLock tag from AlarmListener");
            screenWakeLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);

            Intent service = new Intent(context, AppFireBaseMessagingService.class);
            startWakefulService(context, service);
            screenWakeLock.release();
        }

    }
}
```

It works when the app is opened but when it is killed it does not work.

Comment: OnePlus is pretty aggressive in this case. You can read more about it [here](https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus). To fix the issue, you have to turn off battery optimization for your app in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned code will be stopping your app from entering into Doze mode. Make sure that you are sending Notification object in your Push notification payload. And also you can remove your application from battery optimization

Comment: This will be running in a different process, So better to add your process in the same of Foreground service

Comment: i',m using it for same process

Comment: Can you confirm weather your foregound service is running or not?

Comment: actually i don't have the device and on my device it works well

Comment: Can you please check the push notification response

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you app is excluded from Battery Optimization:
Go To Settings, select "Optimize battery usage", select "all" and make sure that your app is unchecked
Also, Go to Settings/App/Your App/battery and check "Allow background activity"

Comment: This is another resource I found very interesting regarding your problem https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of devices right now which have a very aggressive battery savers, which prevents pushes to be delivered to your app because the OS just kills your app in the background. Devices from practically all manufactures except Google's have this problem. Take a look at this [post](https://onesignal.com/blog/manufacturers-interfere-with-reliable-notifications/)

I have beed dealing with the same, and what we did, is to check if any battery optimization is activated on the device, and send a message to the user to let him know his experience with Pushes will be affected beacuse of this.